# How can i make regular expression for ExtraFields in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

`ExtraFields[milage_1][from]` `ExtraFields[milage_1][to]`

```
ExtraFields[model_year_example_1998_2001_0][from]

ExtraFields[model_year_example_1998_2001_0][to]
```

This is the values i just want to check for `Extrafields and [from]`.

```
i.match(/^ExtraFields.*[f.*.m]/g)
```

but it pass through for both [from] and [to] and i want to only make true if there is [from] only.

Comment: You really need to go read up on the basics of regular expressions. `[f.*.m]` for example is a _character class_, and that is most likely not what you want here.

Comment: I have found the solution Thanks @CBroe for the quick response .

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is remove `[f.*.m]` brackets 
This worked for me `/^ExtraFields.*f.*.m/g`